# Getting values from html string with many <td> tag

Tags: php

I have a string below

```
<?php
$str = '<td>1.06</td><td>9.30</td><td>16.08</td><td style="color:#009">0.70</td><td style="color:#009">3/3.5</td><td style="color:#009">1.00</td><td><font color="blue">L</font></td>';
?>
```

What function help us to get value of each < TD > tag and putting them into an array . Thank friends.

Comment: parsing DOM tree is probably your best option. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_dom_parser_example.htm

Comment: i actually only need to proccess that string . the DOM too much complex for this task . anyway thanks for your help ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use php [DomDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php)

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTMLFile("test.html");
$tables = $dom->getElementsByTagName('table');   

foreach ($table->childNodes as $td) {
  if ($td->nodeName == 'td') {
    echo $td->nodeValue, "\n";
  }
}
```

Comment: `$dom` magically contains tables…? 

Comment: forgot to load the html.. :D  @deceze

Comment: i actually only need to proccess that string . the DOM too much complex for this task . anyway thanks for your help hehe ;)

Comment: @bambostar No, it's the *appropriate* tool for the job. The mistake is to underestimate HTML.